# Minimal covering circle for a matplotlib.PathPatch

Tags: python, matplotlib, bezier

For an arbitrary matplotlib.PathPatch instance and a given origin, I would like to find the circle with the minimal radius that fully covers the patch.
For straight line paths that is straightforward: simply compute the distances between path vertices and the origin; the maximum is the desired radius.
However, for paths with Bezier curves, the path vertices are control points that can lie outside the patch, and hence the circle ends up being too large. How can I find the minimal radius in these cases?

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Find the circle with minimum radius that given an xy origin fully covers a matplotlib.patch.PathPatch instance.
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# arbitrary PathPatch
vertices = np.array([[ 0.44833333, -2.75444444],
                     [-0.78166667, -1.28444444],
                     [-2.88166667,  1.81555556],
                     [-0.75666667,  1.81555556],
                     [-0.28166667,  0.96555556],
                     [ 1.06833333,  3.01555556],
                     [ 1.86833333, -0.13444444],
                     [ 0.86833333, -0.68444444],
                     [ 0.44833333, -2.75444444]])
codes = (1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 79)
ax.add_artist(PathPatch(Path(vertices, codes), color='red'))

# plot control points separately
ax.scatter(*vertices.T, c='black', marker='x')

# covering circle
origin = np.array((0, 0))
deltas = vertices - origin[np.newaxis, :]
distances = np.linalg.norm(deltas, axis=-1)
radius = np.max(distances)
ax.add_artist(plt.Circle(origin, radius, alpha=0.1))

ax.axis([-4, 4, -4, 4])
ax.set_aspect("equal")

plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the actual result you're looking for though? The smallest possible circle around an arbitrary closed path? (e.g. one that touches the path at at least two points?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Not quite. The circle origin is fixed, so I am looking for the circle that encloses the (closed) `Path`/Bezier curve and touches it in at least one position.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I just saw the [book on Bezier curves](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/) in your profile. The section on "flattening" is basically what I have been looking for (as the matplotlib `Path` class does not support interpolation for Bezier curves). Thank you for doing God's work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to work with paths instead of artists. This way you'll be able to use [contains_path](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.contains_path) to check if your circle contains your initial patch.

Additionally, you can use [scipy.optimize.fmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) to find the minimum:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch, Circle

from scipy.optimize import fmin

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# arbitrary PathPatch
vertices = np.array([[ 0.44833333, -2.75444444],
                     [-0.78166667, -1.28444444],
                     [-2.88166667,  1.81555556],
                     [-0.75666667,  1.81555556],
                     [-0.28166667,  0.96555556],
                     [ 1.06833333,  3.01555556],
                     [ 1.86833333, -0.13444444],
                     [ 0.86833333, -0.68444444],
                     [ 0.44833333, -2.75444444]])
codes = (1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 79)
custom_path = Path(vertices, codes) # the path that is supposed to be inside the circle path
ax.add_patch(PathPatch(custom_path, color='red'))

# plot control points separately
ax.scatter(*vertices.T, c='black', marker='x')

# covering circle (init)
origin = np.array((0, 0))
deltas = vertices - origin[np.newaxis, :]
distances = np.linalg.norm(deltas, axis=-1)
radius = np.max(distances)

def patch_in_circle(r):
    circle_path = Path.circle(origin, radius=r)
    if circle_path.contains_path(custom_path):
        return r
    else:
        return radius

r = fmin(patch_in_circle, radius)
ax.add_patch( Circle(origin, radius=r, alpha=0.1))

ax.axis([-4, 4, -4, 4])
ax.set_aspect("equal")

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess I had expected/hoped for some insight into how determine the extents of Bezier curves explicitly rather than an intellectually unsatisfying minimization based on the `Path.contains_path` method. However, this undoubtedly answers the question and is fast enough (0.01 seconds) for my purposes.

Comment: Also: love the url obfuscation in your profile.

Comment: If you're looking for a mathematical solution you might try [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/). Programmers on SO are mostly lazy and hence come with the easiest solution... ;-)

Comment: In case you ever develop an interest for intellectually more stimulating solutions, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans has a book on Bezier curves, and the [section on flattening](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#flattening) outlines how to approximate Bezier curves with line segments. The end-points of these lines could then be used to find the radius. However, until I implement his pseudocode in python, I, too, will be lazy and use your solution. ;-)